# Install Sonata Dashboard bundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I want to install Sonata Dashboard bundle, so I follow [these](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/dashboard/master/doc/reference/installation.html) steps.

After installing and configuring I get an error:

*Compile Error: Declaration of Application\Sonata\DashboardBundle\Entity\Dashboard::getId() must be compatible with Sonata\DashboardBundle\Model\Dashboard::getId(): ?int*

I use Symfony 3.4, php 7.2 and composer.json looks like:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "enqueue/amqp-lib": "^0.8.23",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.3",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^2.1",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "liip/monitor-bundle": "^2.6",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^3.2",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.34",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "^3.12",
    "sonata-project/cache": "1.x-dev",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "2.4",
    "sonata-project/classification-bundle": "^3.6",
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "^3.9",
    "sonata-project/dashboard-bundle": "^0.3.0",
    "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "2.3",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-extensions": "^1.0",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.5",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.5",
    "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "^3.4",
    "sonata-project/google-authenticator": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "^3.12",
    "sonata-project/news-bundle": "3.4",
    "sonata-project/notification-bundle": "^3.5",
    "sonata-project/seo-bundle": "^2.5",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^4.1",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
    "symfony/templating": "3.4.8",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
},
```

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the generated entity misses the return type hints… probably [a bug in Sonata Easy Extends bundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataEasyExtendsBundle/blob/2.x/src/Resources/skeleton/orm/entity.mustache#L27). You can add type hint by finding and modifying `Application\Sonata\DashboardBundle\Entity\Dashboard`

Comment: Now I modify function in Dashboard.php to: public function getId(): ?int {return $this->id;}. Now everything works fine, except when I go to URL: admin/sonata/dashboard/dashboard/create, then it throws me another error: Type error: Return value of Sonata\DashboardBundle\Model\Dashboard::getEnabled() must be of the type boolean, null returned

Comment: sounds like another bug, there should be a default value here: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDashboardBundle/blob/master/src/Model/Dashboard.php#L66 You could override the setter to set it to whatever you think should be the default, true or false.